# app showing up in bookmarks on facebook web, but not in bookmarks on facebook mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, bookmarks

My app "Butter Picks" is showing up in the left-hand-side bookmarks in the regular Facebook web view, but it does not show up in the bookmarks on my iPhone. I've surveyed all the relevant documentation and can't find any setting that needs to be changed. If I use the search within FB iPhone app to find "Butter Picks" I can find the app and use it as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#bookmarks - bookmarks are only shown for native apps inside the Facebook iPhone app, the mobile site should have a bookmark for any mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Igy pointed out in a comment, bookmarks are only shown for native apps inside the Facebook iPhone app. The mobile site should have a bookmark for any mobile app.